# Unable to run 'display notification' using osascript in a tmux session

Tags: applescript, tmux

If I run the following command in Apple Script Editor directly,

```
display notification "Hello, world"
```

I can see a  notification as expected

However if I tried to invoke it via command line:

```
 osascript  -e 'display notification "Hello, world"'
```

It turns out I am running it in a tmux session. If I just ran the command in my default shell, it works as expected.

How can I get it to work with tmux?

Comment: The `osascript` line works fine for me…

Comment: Are you doing it over ssh? What version of OS X?

Comment: I ran it in a tmux session. Apparently it did not work if I call it in a tmux session, but works fine in my default shell. Strange

Comment: This might be caused by the same issue complicating tmux access to the OS X pasteboard.  See [here](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/blob/master/README.md) for details, and check if installing *reattach-to-user-namespace* (`brew install reattach-to-user-namespace` if you are running Homebrew) helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @kopischke said, install or upgrade `reattach-to-user-namespace` may solve this problem.

If your `reattach-to-user-namespace` is old, notification works well after `brew upgrade reattach-to-user-namespace`.

Comment: And add the line to ~/.tmux.conf  set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"

Answer (score 3):

Building on @snomof's answer, you'll want to install [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) through Homebrew or MacPorts and wrap the call to `osascript`:

```
reattach-to-user-namespace osascript  -e 'display notification "Hello, world"'
```

Comment: And add the line to ~/.tmux.conf  set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"